# Can post-glacial (icesheet) landforms be present on the warm desert (BWh/BWc)?

Tags: internal-consistency, climate, geography, geology

How realistic would it be to have moraines and dried lakes on deserts? I plan to have a salt lake with a few rivers flowing in - how much time would they have to erode canyons?

Natural disasters causing mass extinctions - like flyby of asteroid which changed the position of planet closer to sun or volcanic activity which temporary caused snowball not-Earth - are allowed but only if time-frame allows the remaining organisms to evolve into humans.

Ideally I mean BWh climate but if not possible BWc is good as well.

Comment: The remaining what will evolve into humans?

Comment: @NomadMaker organisms (fixed)

Comment: Why would any organisms evolve into humans?

Comment: @NomadMaker Because of natural selection preferring organisms adhering to handwavium principle? My world has humans so any history needs to be consistent with humans there. If there was a catastrophe 1000 years ago that wiped out all land multicellular organisms it's not allowed as an answer. On the other hand forcing animals to adapt rapidly to changing climate in 10,000 is perfectly OK as humans or apes can survive.

Comment: Yes, but evolution does *not* prefer humans.

Comment: @NomadMaker which is why this is worldbuilding.se instead of biology.se. Some does of willing suspention of disbelief is required.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. See: Utah.

Pretty much all of Utah county is a former dry lake bed, with Utah Lake, draining into the Great Salt Lake, being all that is left of the former Lake Bonneville inland sea, which all drained cataclysmically after it rose high enough to break the dam into the Snake River plain. The surrounding mountains also formerly held glaciers which fed into the lake, but those are all gone now as the whole area, despite having excellent high-altitude skiing snow, is in fact a desert.